# Flutter firebase notification not working when app is killer

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to implement firebase notification for my flutter application with the latest version which works perfectly when inside the app and when the app is running in the background and not killed. But when the app is killer the notification doesn't show on the notification bar and not sure what am doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
   print('getInitialMessage data: ${message.data}');
     });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          print('onMessageOpenedApp data: ${message.data}');
        });
     
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print('onMessage data: ${message.data}');
     });
```

And inside my `main.dart` is like below:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}



void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ConnectionStatusSingleton connectionStatus = ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance();
  connectionStatus.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);


}
```

And my manifest is as below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packagename">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <!-- android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
         -->

    <application
        android:label="App Name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="MyNavigationService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" >
            <!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
        </service>
        <!-- Add the following entry, with your API key -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDyLeRnGmwYrcQdyheVtZL5nLOpAjnSeVc"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <!--meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" /-->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <!--meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="1" /-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I will be glad help to resolve this. And if there is any further information needed kindly let me know.

Comment: Are you checking on latest Android 13 OS ?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest OS 13

Comment: Then permission for notification for this app creating issue. check for the same